# scanning binary sequences of length n with k 1's and n-k 0's

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinations, permutation, bit

I want to write a loop that scans all binary sequences of length n with k 1's and n-k 0's.

Actually, in each iteration an action is performed on the sequence and if a criterion is met the loop will break, otherwise it goes to next sequence. (I am not looking for `nchoosek` or `perms` since for large values of n it takes so much time to give the output).

What MATLAB code do you suggest?

Comment: Wasn't this same question [asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965045/all-binary-sequences-of-length-n-with-k-1s-and-n-k-0s)? Seems to be removed now, I believe there were at least some helpful comments there.

Comment: so do all zeros follow all ones (vice-a-versa)?

Comment: @BasSwinckels All comments/answers were using `c++`, but I need `MATLAB` code/algorithm.

Comment: @Parag No! All combination of such sequences without any exception.

Comment: Why the question is downvoted? Please tell me to improve it. Thanks

Comment: @BasSwinckels: +1 there were good suggestions indeed: using `std::next_permutation` in C++, and [Gosper's Bit Twiddling Hack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation)

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi you got C++ answers last time because you tagged it C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement something like an [iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)/[generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29) pattern:

```
classdef Iterator < handle
    properties (SetAccess = private)
        n              % sequence length
        counter        % keeps track of current iteration
    end

    methods
        function obj = Iterator(n)
            % constructor
            obj.n = n;
            obj.counter = 0;
        end

        function seq = next(obj)
            % get next bit sequence
            if (obj.counter > 2^(obj.n) - 1)
                error('Iterator:StopIteration', 'Stop iteration')
            end
            seq = dec2bin(obj.counter, obj.n) - '0';
            obj.counter = obj.counter + 1;
        end

        function tf = hasNext(obj)
            % check if sequence still not ended
            tf = (obj.counter <= 2^(obj.n) - 1);
        end

        function reset(obj)
            % reset the iterator
            obj.counter = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

Now you can use it as:

```
k = 2;
iter = Iterator(4);
while iter.hasNext()
    seq = iter.next();
    if sum(seq)~=k, continue, end
    disp(seq)
end
```

In the example above, this will iterate through all 0/1 sequences of length 4 with exactly k=2 ones:

```
 0     0     1     1
 0     1     0     1
 0     1     1     0
 1     0     0     1
 1     0     1     0
 1     1     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems nice. For the case I'm facing I must skip the cases where the number of 1's is not the desired k? Or there is a better solution?

Comment: you could add a test to the loop: `if sum(seq)~=k, continue, end`

Comment: Is there any way to make it faster? Unfortunately, `nchoosek` works much faster

Comment: did you look at the answers in the question I linked to, there are some very clever ideas. If you absolutely want speed, just implement the previous suggestions in C/C++ as a MEX-function and call it in your code...